# discord.py авто-выдача ролей при подключении нового участника сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Мне надо, чтобы при подключении участника ему выдавалась определенная роль. В интернете находил, но у меня не работало. Вот код (без команды на выдачу ролей):

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        # bot connection
        print('Присоеденился {0}!'.format(self.user))

    
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # so that the bot does not display its own messages
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        # displaying messages from the chat
        if message.content.startswith(''):
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author} написал {message.content}')

# bot launch
client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Если не сложно, объясните еще как работает выдача ролей, а то практически ничего не понимаю в этой библиотеке.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot started")


@bot.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    # so that the bot does not display its own messages
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    # displaying messages from the chat
    if message.content.startswith(''):
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author} написал {message.content}')


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = member.guild.get_role(role_id=id_роли)
    await member.add_roles(role)


bot.run("Токен")
```

Прочитать про функцию `add_roles`, можно в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Member.add_roles).

Зайдите на [сайт](https://discord.com/developers) и выберите своего бота, после включите эти 2 пункта(Они находятся во вкладке Bot).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня не сработало. Мой друг присоединился, но роль ему не выдалась. Если знаете решение и вам не трудно, можете помочь?

Comment: @fromicks, можете скинуть ошибку?

Comment: Ошибки нет, он просто не выдает роль

Comment: @fromicks, у бота есть права для выдачи роли? Намерения(intents'ы) для пользователя?

Comment: У него права администратора, я так понял надо убрать эти права и дать ему определенные?

Comment: @fromick, если у него права администратора, значит не в них дело. Я изменил ответ, попробуйте также.

Comment: Все равно не выдалась может я здесь ошибку допустил:
    async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
        # Получаем роль
        role = member.guild.get_role(role_id=айди роли)
        # Выдаём роль пользователю
        await member.add_roles(role)